# What is the difference between function name() and name = function() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

AFAIK, there are two ways of creating functions:

```
function name()
{
}
```

and,

```
name = function()
{
}
```

I always use the second one as it seems much more intuitive.

**What is the difference between these two ways of creating functions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that first case function is defined at parse-time for a script block, whereas second case function is defined at run-time.

From here: [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: You've copied from and linked to a poor answer. Ignore the massive upvotes on that answer.

Comment: @amnotiam care to explain why the answer is poor? Seems mighty fine to me...

Comment: @Bane: Read [the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname#comment10856857_336868) from [Šime Vidas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/425275/ime-vidas). All functions are defined when code runs, not when syntax is parsed. An answer shouldn't get 300+ votes if it doesn't accurately answer the question.